# React <Nav.Link href > trying to link and scroll to one of the <div> in another component on the same page

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Here is the code:

Navigation.js

```
  <Navbar.Collapse id="basic-navbar-nav">
            <Nav className="mr-auto">
              <Nav.Link href="???"> Pokeman </Nav.Link>
     </Nav>
```

I am trying to link to the same page div section in one of my components:
Content.js

```
  <div id="Pokeman">
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using anchor links (via the `#hash` sign) should work:

```js
<Nav.Link href="#Pokeman">
  Pokeman
</Nav.Link>
```

Comment: Nevermind, this is so wired, i tried earlier it didn't work, but now it works. -.-